# Release/Delete *.dll at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, runtime

I have a `WinForm` application and on startup I extract a *.dll from the embedded resources (Properties.Resources).

My application needs this later (Ionic.Zip-library). But when the application closes, how can I then delete this *.dll? Because now I get an error that `the access is denied`

Do I first need to un-reference it? Or is there even another way to completely let the *.dll inside my *.exe? Because at the end it should only be one *.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unload a loaded dll from a running AppDomain.

You can however start a new [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx), load the dll there, and afterwards, when you are closing the application, [unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx) the AppDomain. After you have unloaded the AppDomain, the extracted dll is no longer referenced by the the running process, and can be deleted.

This however has a consequence - you can only use you extracted dll inside the created AppDomain.  [Some googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=c#sclient=psy-ab&q=appdomain+how+does+it+work&oq=appdomain+how+does+it+work&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30.3229.7443.0.7540.34.22.3.1.1.1.489.3321.4j7j2j3j1.17.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.psy-ab.5Gu5w2JTjVk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZWU&fp=339fc13c43b84b72&biw=1344&bih=733) might give you more information.

Comment: I've googled around a bit. But faced another problem, I create a new AppDomain now, and there I'll load the *.dll, but i have to remove it in VS from references, right? but then the compiler complains about he doesnt know `Ionic.Zip`. How can I tell him that I'll load the dll later?

Comment: You'll have to make a separate assembly which IS referencing the Ionic.zip dll. You'll also have to create a class in this assembly which starts the code which uses the Ionic.zip dll. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578195/261050